# Disable CD/DVD Burner but keep CD/DVD reader in Windows

Tags: windows-7, burning

I have a laptop with Win7 installed on it. I am running it with separate accounts, and I manage the only administrator account.

I would like to disable the ability to burn CDs/DVDs  - as that can be done even if no burning software is installed, and without administrator rights, by downloading, for instance, a portable version of CDBurnerXP-, but still keep the ability to read CDs/DVDs. From the device manager, I can only disable both at once.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Nero, I believe it doesn't allow non-admin users to burn discs by default, unless you explicitly allow them to do so using [Nero BurnRights](http://www.nero.com/ena/downloads/):

[image: 1]

But this of course (as you stated) will not prevent users from simply using portable apps. I don't think a perfect 100% block is possible. At best you can use the Local Group Policy Editor (`Run / gpedit.msc`) to disable the built-in disc burning features by enabling:

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Explorer\Remove CD Burning Features
```

Then you can enable:

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Don't run specified Windows applications
```

and add all known disc-burning executables to the block list.